# Is it possible to mark GSettings/GSchema <flags> as translatable?

Tags: translation, gettext, gsettings

I have a GSchema defining some flags like so:

```
<flags id="org.example.program">
    <value nick="ENGLISH_WORD" value="1"/>
    <value nick="ANOTHER_WORD" value="2"/>
</flags>
```

However I have been informed by a translator that these are not processed by gettext or offered in the .pot file. Is there a way I can mark these as translatable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default values can be translated but the translations are substituted from .mo files at runtime.  You have to put the textdomain in the attribute "gettext-domain" of the "<schemalist>" resp. "<schema>" element.  You also have to put the locale category into the attribute "category" of the "<default>" element.  Read the paragraph "Description" in https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html for more information.

I recommend that you examine the sources of a recent Gtk application and see how the different components are localized.  GNU gettext has recently been improved to offer better support for localizing desktop applications and therefore the process is currently evolving.  In particular, you usually no longer need intltool.

Comment: Excellent answer, I clearly remember reading that but it just didn't make it to my brain. I already have the "gettext-domain" attribute set on "schemalist"; is it necessary to put it on "schema" as well, or is the top level enough?

FWIW I'm using meson to generate the pot, po and mo files; not sure if that uses intltool or not.

Comment: I think it depends on the desired scope (entire schemalist or just one schema), where to put the "gettext-domain" attribute.  But I'm only guessing here.  Gedit (my usual source for stealing Gtk boilerplate code) puts it on the schema elements, see https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/blob/master/data/org.gnome.gedit.gschema.xml.in.

Comment: After some quick testing, "schemalist" seems to do it, but I still can't get gettext to recognize enum nick's, except for the "default" tag. Oh well, a translator of mine found a way to hack around it to his satisfaction, GSchema support would be nice, but I guess that's not what enum nicks are for.